# Android Client send object to C socket server fails

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, network-programming

I have made a Android socket program which acts as client. A c socket server is running which does recv on the socket.
**read** gets executed multiple number of times even though I am sending payload structure just once.

It send the following data:

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public class DataToServer implements Externalizable {

    public int id;
    public int cmd;
    public byte active;
    public byte level;
    public byte group;

    public DataToServer(int id, int cmd, byte active, byte level, byte group) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.cmd = cmd;
        this.active = active;
        this.level = level;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public DataToServer() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCmd() {
        return cmd;
    }

    public void setCmd(int cmd) {
        this.cmd = cmd;
    }

    public byte getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(byte active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public byte getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(byte level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public byte getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(byte group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        this.id = input.readInt( );
        this.cmd = input.readInt();
        this.active = input.readByte();
        this.level = input.readByte(); 
        this.group = input.readByte();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output) throws IOException {
        output.writeInt(id);
        output.writeInt(cmd);
        output.writeByte(active);
        output.writeByte(level);
        output.writeByte(group);
    }   
}
```

Next I send it through the following Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 3456;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.10";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }

    public void sendData(View view){
        try{
            OutputStream objStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream ObjOpStream = new ObjectOutputStream(objStream);
            byte active = 65;
            byte level = (byte)150;
            byte group = (byte) 255;
            DataToServer data = new DataToServer();
            data.setId(10);
            data.setCmd(15);
            data.setActive(active);
            data.setLevel(level);
            data.setGroup(group);
            ObjOpStream.writeObject(data);
            ObjOpStream.close();
            objStream.close();

        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddress,SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

On the C server side I have following code to receive.

```
struct dali_payload
{
        int id;
        int cmd;
        char active;
        char level;
        char group;
};



  printf("Payload size: %d\n", sizeof(dp));
    while(1)
    {
        read_size = read(client_sock ,&dp ,sizeof(dp));
        if(read_size <= 0)
            break;
        printf("Received bytes: %d\n", read_size);
        printf("Id: %x\n", (dp.id));
        printf("cmd: %x\n",(dp.cmd));
        printf("active: %x\n", (dp.active));
        printf("level: %x\n", (dp.level));
        printf("group: %x\n", (dp.group));
    }

OUTPUT:
Socket created
bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
Connection accepted
Payload size: 12
Received bytes: 2
Id: edac
cmd: 0
active: 0
level: 0
group: 0
Received bytes: 2
Id: 500
cmd: 0
active: 0
level: 0
group: 0
Received bytes: 1
Id: 573
cmd: 0
active: 0
level: 0
group: 0
Received bytes: 12
Id: 632a0072
cmd: 652e6d6f
active: 78
level: 61
group: 6d
Received bytes: 12
Id: 612e656c
cmd: 6f72646e
active: 69
level: 64
group: 73
Received bytes: 12
Id: 74656b63
cmd: 6f6d6564
active: 2e
level: 44
group: 61
Received bytes: 12
Id: 536f5461
cmd: 65767265
active: 72
level: 87
group: 2b
Received bytes: 12
Id: e51d8e7a
cmd: cc0
active: 78
level: 70
group: 77
Received bytes: 12
Id: a000000
cmd: f000000
active: 41
level: 96
group: ff
```

**read** gets executed multiple number of times even though I am sending payload structure just once.

The output shows some constant data received every time. only the last 12 bytes are the correct data.

Where is the problem. Is the Android code for sending object correct. Or my read call has some error I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
recv(client_sock ,&dp ,1, 0);
```

will read `1` byte at a time. Most probably that's *not* what you want.

Ideally, you should put the length of the supplied buffer as the third argument.

Assuming `dp` is defined as

```
struct dali_payload dp;
```

you can use something like

```
 read_size = recv(client_sock ,&dp ,sizeof(dp), 0);
```

Comment: @ianand I was talking about `socklen_t*)&c` part. It does not have a matching starting `(`

Comment: that got deleted when i was formatting it to make in one line. sorry for that. please verify

Comment: A constant data which is not my packet is received. Only the last 12 bytes are my packet.